# Limiting number of visible links displayed with wp_link_pages

Tags: pagination, wp-link-pages, paginate-links

I need to extend the wp_link_page function to only show a max of 5 links at a time. What is the best approach to limit the number of links?

In the end i'd like it to look like this: ***Previous 1 2 3 4 5 ... Next***

I've already used [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37256/wp-link-pages-numbers-and-next-previous) to generate the prev/next buttons along side the numbers.

Comment: You're talking about [tag:pagination] and _not_ about `wp_link_pages()`. Please do some research before posting.

Comment: No no no my friend i'm talking about interior post pages using <!--nextpage--> and in that case yes you would use wp_link_pages.

Comment: The pagination plugin "pagebar" does contains this functionality. You can find it in the repository.

Comment: Was there ever any progress with this question?

Comment: I cannot make it works but there might be a way to do this with `wp_link_pages_link` filter hook. 
Example: `add_filter('wp_link_pages_link', 'hookLinkPagesLink', 11, 2); function hookLinkPagesLink($link, $i) {// your code here}`
`$link` is generated href link and `$i` is current loop.
There are also another global variables such as `$numpages` is total pages, `$page` is current page.