# Adding an Unlinked Space in a Custom Function

Tags: php, functions, wp-link-pages

This question has been a pain in my side for the last few days.

I am using a function to display page numbers and next/previous links with WP_LINK_PAGES.  The code I'm using (below) is a shortened version of the code found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37256/paged-posts-how-to-use-numbers-and-next-previous-links) - to the best of my knowledge, it is correct.  (Go easy on me, just diving into PHP.)

[Please view the working example here.](http://themeforward.com/demo2/?page_id=2&page=2)

The problem should be a simple fix, but I can't figure it out.  **I would like to add a space in front of the "Next Page" link which is *not* linked itself to the next page in order for the pagination to have equal spacing.**

```
function wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add($args)
{
    global $page, $numpages, $more, $pagenow;

    if($page-1) # there is a previous page
        $args['before'] .= _wp_link_page($page-1)
            . $args['link_before']. $args['previouspagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
        ;

    if ($page<$numpages) # there is a next page
        $args['after'] = _wp_link_page($page+1)
            . $args['link_before'] . $args['nextpagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
        ;

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use css for this? Do you want to add a space between 3(last page) and Next page ?

Comment: Agreed, you should be using CSS to do this, probably `margin`, rather than hard-coding the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion CSS isn't the right way, it should be a "real" space.
Also there is no class to target the differents links in the string.

Try this code:

```
    function wp_link_pages_args_prevnext_add($args)
{
    global $page, $numpages, $more, $pagenow;

    if($page-1) # there is a previous page
        $args['before'] .= ' '. _wp_link_page($page-1) 
            . $args['link_before'] . $args['previouspagelink']  . '</a>' . ' '
        ;

    if ($page<$numpages) # there is a next page
        $args['after'] = ' '. _wp_link_page($page+1)
           . $args['link_before'] . $args['nextpagelink']  . '</a>'
            . $args['after'] 
        ;

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: ^ I can't even express how much frustration you just curbed, you are the man.